# Layout Orientation conflicting with manifest

Tags: android, screen-orientation

In the manifest file of this application, I have specified the screen orientation to be landscape for each activity. However, in each layout file it lists android:orientation="vertical" as default. The application sometimes crashes, sometimes it doesn't, could these values be conflicting?

Comment: Please post the error you get in logcat.  9/10 the answer is in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way, it is different things at all.

Landscape for activity mean how to show activity for user

android:orientation="vertical" for LinearLayout mean how LinearLayout will draw its children views

Comment: Ignore the above statement, it was due to an image with too high a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`android:orientation` in layout defines how the child view will be stacked on the screen (for example see [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)). The orientation in the manifest is all about the [screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) orientation (or the orientation of specific Activity).